# How to use twig rendering for making files?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I would like to use twig to make js file.

These are what I want to do.

web/base.js

```
// this is my base file
alert("this file is created by " + "{{var}}");
```

Then in my Command 
`/src/Acme/TopBundle/Command/genFileCommand.php`

```
class genFileCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output){    
        $var = 'whitebear';
       //then some how pass the this value to twig and make file here

    }
}
```

Finally, I want make this file be created.

/web/gen/generated.js

```
// this is my base file
alert("this file is created by " + "whitebear");
```

It might be a irregular way to use twig in this way though, twig is very simple and good rendering system.

If I can do this way, code is more readable and good for maintenance.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way should be to place your javascript base file inside the view folder from `Twig`, then render the base template with you vars and save the output with `file_put_contents` to the `gen` folder.

Comment: Thanks This is simple than I thought. I tried and works.